# Resizable popup in WPF toolkit autocompletebox

Tags: wpftoolkit, autocompletebox

Is there a way to make the popup of WPF toolkit autocompletebox resizable (by adding the resize gripper)? But firstly, can it be accessed in the xaml file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

http://kentb.blogspot.co.at/2007/04/resizer-wpf-control.html

```
<kb:Resizer xmlns:kb="http://kent.boogaart/controls">
    Content
</kb:Resizer>
```

The Resizer control adds resizing behaviour to the content you place within it. The default template uses a ResizeGrip and allows the user to drag the grip in order to resize the content. For example, here is how you might add resizing behaviour to a TextBox (XML namespace mapping assumed from hereon in):

```
<kb:Resizer>
   <TextBox>My TextBox</TextBox>
</kb:Resizer>
```